# Rails - Using test database with pow test domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I'm currently using [Pow](http://pow.cx/manual.html) to manage my Rails app, and have both .dev and .test running. I was wondering how to set up .test domain to use the test database instead of the development one.

Basically, can I have appname.dev with a development environment loaded, and appname.test with a test environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a variation of [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/2914870) to determine the domain being accessed, and have the Rails app behave accordingly from then on.

You'd add a before_filter on your Application Controller that sets `session[:site]` according to whether it's a development or testing environment (with the option to pass either `site=development` or `site=testing` from the standard Rails server as well).

Here's what I think would be the relevant excerpt of the Gist linked above:

```
session[:site] = case request.domain
  when "appname.dev" then "development"
  when "appname.test" then "testing"
  else ENV['site'] || "development"
end
```

The rest of your Rails app would behave according to the value of `session[:site]`. I wrote a bit more about multi-site Rails apps [here](http://www.commonmediainc.com/blog/how-serve-multi-site-rails-apps-and-use-pow-make-it-easy), as well.